# Selenium Web driver: how do I click on image button?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is the image button source:

```html
<img src="/NU/b-nb.gif" border="0" name="New Business" label="New Business" xpath=".">
```

I'm trying to click on the image button on IE using selenium webdriver but I'm unable to find the element.

Comment: `I'm unable to find` describe it first...

Comment: There is an image button where I need to click on it. If I inspect element using IE I will get above mentioned HTML code. How do I click on that button

Comment: I mean what have you tried and what is the error you are getting.. share that as well

Comment: Tried locating the element using name, xpath etc. but it simply cannot locate the element.

Comment: did you try to find element with `WebDriverWait`???

Comment: No I haven't ...Please describe it.

Comment: `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("New Business")));el.click();`..like this

Comment: look if the element is under frame

Comment: The element is located inside the frame.

Comment: Then you need to switch that frame before finding element like `driver.switchTo().frame("frame name or id")`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select element by name or some other approach & simple call the click event using click() method.

```
  WebElement myImgBtn= driver.findElement(By.name("New Business"));
  myImgBtn.click();
```

As, you have this element in other html frame. So you have to switch the driver to that iframe before selection of element.

e.g.

```
    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@id,'your_iframe_id')]")));

    WebElement myImgBtn= driver.findElement(By.name("New Business"));
    myImgBtn.click();
```

Comment: Webdriver is throwing an error : No such element is found.

Comment: name can be assigned not only to image! it will click on the first one that its catch, No such element is found (look if you have frame/iframe)

Comment: Yes, it's html frame only.

Comment: switch the driver to the iframe before selection, I have edited the changes in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@name='New Business']")).click();
```